# How to initialize Labels in Label Array using foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, foreach, iteration

I want to create 32 labels in my Form so I used code like this:

```
//using System.Windows.Forms;
Label[] Lb_clubs;
Lb_clubs = new Label[32];
foreach(Label lb in Lb_clubs)
{
  lb = new Label();
  lb.Text = "somename";
  //and other codes
}
```

But I am getting an error

> CS1656 : Cannot assign lb because it is a foreach iteration variable.

Any Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign to the `lb` variable, because it's a `foreach` iteration variable, so it's in a read-only context. That's why you're getting [Compiler Error CS1656](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1656):

> This error occurs when an assignment to variable occurs in a read-only context. Read-only contexts include foreach iteration variables, using variables, and fixed variables. To resolve this error, avoid assignments to a statement variable in `using` blocks, `foreach` statements, and `fixed` statements.

Try a `for`-loop:

```
Label[] Lb_clubs;
Lb_clubs = new Label[32];
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    var lb = new Label();
    lb.Text = "somename";
    //and other codes
    Lb_clubs[i] = lb;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop as described by the @Phils and @rickvdbosch, but you can keep you foreach loop by using `Enumerable.Select`:

```
//using System.Windows.Forms;
Label[] Lb_clubs;
Lb_clubs = new Label[32].Select(lbl => new Label()).ToArray();
foreach (Label lb in Lb_clubs)
{
    lb.Text = "somename";
    //and other codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a for loop, not foreach

```
            Label[] Lb_clubs;
            Lb_clubs = new Label[32];

            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            {
                var lb = new Label();
                lb.Text = "somename";
                //and other codes
                Lb_clubs[i] = lb;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value in a `foreach` loop: you should also see the `lb = new Label();` marked in the editor, which should tell you that it

> Cannot assign to 'lb' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

which generates a [Compiler Error CS1656](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1656).

You can do this (besides what others have already suggested) in one line, using [Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Range);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var Lb_clubs = Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Select(l => new Label() { Text = "SomeText" }).ToArray();
```

Slightly different, adding a progressive value to the text, using the index of the enumeration and also assign a Name (and/or other values) to the Label, if needed:

```
var Lb_clubs = Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Select(idx => new Label() { 
    Text = "SomeText" + idx.ToString(), 
    Name = "SomeName" + idx.ToString() }).ToArray();
```